# Power BI how to create and add new visualization to PowerBIVisualsPlayground?

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to learn how to create a new power bi visualization. I've cloned the GitHub repository and looked to the code but did not manage to fully understand the architecture. I've added a testVisualization.ts in visuals folder and testVisualization.capabilities.ts in the capabilities folder. What code do I need to add and where in order to see my testVisualization in the PowerBIVisualsPlayground?? A step by step mini example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at how I did it for my repo.  The repo is somewhat behind the master branch, but you should see all the changes I made to make it work. Look at the changes to the files under the playground path.  If you don't need a specific sample data view (I did) you can not make that part of the change.

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/compare/master...LukaszPawlowski-MS:master

Comment: Thank your for your help. Initially I was confused about the table and some other visuals not being in the playground but plugins for them were created . What I was missing was adding them to visualPluginService.ts.